# Interactive output window Text Editor? not REPL

Tags: python, package, sublimetext3, interactive

I don't know what is this function or package I should install called (I'm still quite green to Python)

For instance,

```
e=int(input('guess the number I'm thinking'))
if e==3:
    print('you guessed it！')
else:
    print('oops, you are wrong')
```

My SublimeText output only asks for the number, after I input the number, nothing happens.

So I'm wondering if there is a package for allowing output window feed inputs back to the code and continue running it. 
Is it what REPL is for??

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem, but the apostrophe in `I'm` needs escaping `I\'m`. (or use double quotes to quote the entire phrase).

Comment: You can use SublimeREPL or Terminus for this (Terminus is recommended as it's actively maintained). The short version of your problem is, without some external package of some kind, you can't run interact with a program you're executing.